# D3JS data load and update

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I am using D3JS library in order to load a CSV data named "data.csv". By clicking on the button, I output on the console the data length.
My problem is that if I change the data inside "data.csv" between two actions on the button, the data won't update.

For example, I have one CSV with 100 data and another one with 200. Firstly I put my 100 data CSV in my folder and press the "Read" button, I can check on the console the data length, it is as expected "Data length = 100". After that, I overwrite the CSV file with the 200 data one and press the button again, the console still displays the same data length (100), my data variable has not been updated with the new data from the new file.

How can I solve my data update problem ?

**HTML**

```
<button onclick="read_data()">Read</button>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function read_data(){
    Plotly.d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {
        console.log("Data length = " + data.length)
    })
}
```

Comment: Your browser is probably caching the data file. You could try disabling the cache temporarily (with DevTools open in Chrome, go to Network and click Disable Cache). You will need to keep DevTools open for this work.

Comment: You are right, my browser was caching the data file. Is there a work around with some coding ? I guess that the way I am loading data is not standard, if I want to reload some new data, should I change the filename ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Andrew pointed out browser might be caching the file. Maybe you could add query parameter, for example:

```
function read_data(){
     Plotly.d3.csv("data.csv?”+(new Date()).getTime(), function(error, data) {
         console.log("Data length = " + data.length)
 })}
```

Comment: Thank you it worked. I am not accurate with query, does it specify a filename with a particular time ?

Comment: Yes it would add epoch time as query parameter.