# D3.Js collapsible tree binds with old data after file update

Tags: d3.js, flask

I'm using the following collapsible tree code to render my data https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083. While it reads from the specified file the first time and renders correctly, on further updates to the file it continues to display the old data.

Structure of Json file is as follows :

```
{
 "name": "ArnavG",
 "children": [
  {
   "name": "11th Building",
   "children": [
     {"name": "17:10 - 22:54", "size": 1}
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "12th Building",
   "children": [
     {"name": "02:11 - 04:19", "size": 1},
     {"name": "03:32 - 19:51", "size": 1}
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "15th Building",
   "children": [
     {"name": "16:29 - 19:38", "size": 1},
     {"name": "15:08 - 21:20", "size": 1}
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "16th Building",
   "children": [
     {"name": "01:48 - 02:11", "size": 1},
     {"name": "08:09 - 23:50", "size": 1}
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "18th Building",
   "children": [
     {"name": "20:58 - 22:35", "size": 1}
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "19th Building",
   "children": [
     {"name": "23:57 - 23:59", "size": 1}
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "20th Building",
   "children": [
     {"name": "22:10 - 22:45", "size": 1}
   ]
  }
 ]
}
```

File reading :

```
d3.json("../static/query1.json", function(error, values) {
              if (error) throw error;

              root = values;
              root.x0 = height / 2;
              root.y0 = 0;

              function collapse(d) {
                if (d.children) {
                  d._children = d.children;
                  d._children.forEach(collapse);
                  d.children = null;
                }
              }

              root.children.forEach(collapse);
              update(root);
            });
```

Also, what is 'values' in the above code snippet?

Comment: here `values` is the json response you get on making ajax call to `"../static/query1.json"`

Comment: browser might be caching the json

Comment: What do I do in that case @ChiragKothari ?

Comment: See is this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38580624/d3js-data-load-and-update/38581196#38581196